# Not allowing to push duplicate items into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, push

Basically I'm pushing containers into an array, and once one has been pushed, I don't want to allow that same one to be pushed again.

Here is my JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Dmcg/3/

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var favorites = [];
var counter = 0;

    $('.containers').on('click', function(){

        favorites.push($(this).clone())

        $('.favorite').append(favorites);
    });


});
```

I need to find a way to work around that.

Comment: Add an `e`, for example, `$('.containers').one('click',`

Comment: You could also add a `$(this).data('favorites', true)`

Comment: Not sure I understand. I tried the JSFiddle and each container is only pushed once as far as I can see. Do you mean you don't want containers with the same content to be pushed more than once?

Answer (score 4):

Unless there's more to that click event, you can use the `.one()` method in place of `.on` to get this functionality.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var favorites = [];
    var counter = 0;

    $('.containers').one('click', function(){

        favorites.push($(this).clone())

        $('.favorite').append(favorites);
    });    

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9Dmcg/4/

Even if there were more to it, you could still use `.one()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var favorites = [];
    var counter = 0;

    $('.containers').one('click', function(){

        favorites.push($(this).clone())

        $('.favorite').append(favorites);

        $(this).on("click",function(){
             alert("Favorite Added!");
        }).triggerHandler("click");

    });    

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9Dmcg/5/

Answer (score 1):

Try to check for element id's I would say. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var favorites = [];
var counter = 0;

    $('.containers').bind('click', function(){
        var isAdded = false;
        for (var f = 0; f < favorites.length; f++) {
            console.log(favorites[f].id + "|" + this.id);
             if (favorites[f].id === this.id)
                 isAdded = true;
        }

        if (!isAdded)
            favorites.push($(this).clone()[0])


         console.log(favorites);
        $('.favorite').append(favorites);
    });


});
```

And here's working example -> http://jsfiddle.net/9Dmcg/7/

mz

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the JS Proxy (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Following is the code to create an array which will not accept duplication entry

```
var arr = new Proxy([], {
  get: function(target, key) {
    return target[key];
  },
  set: function(target, key, value){
    if(target.indexOf(value)>=0) return false;
    target[key] = value;
    return true
  }
});
arr.push(100);
arr.push(100); // this will throw error
```

In the above code, we are modifying the default behaviour of array as the set method will be called on any modification done on the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the element already exists:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var favorites = [];

    $('.containers').on('click', function(){
        var found = false;
        for(var i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++)
        {
            if (favorites[i] == $(this)) found = true;
        }
        if (!found) favorites.push($(this).clone())

        $('.favorite').append(favorites);
    });


});
```

Comment: The problem is, `favorites[i]` will never be equal to `$(this)` because they are two different elements, even if they have the same contents/attributes. `var a = {}; var b = {}; console.log(a == b); // false`

Comment: how do you mean that, why will they be different?

Comment: see my updated comment, two different objects will never be equal. .clone() creates a new element, thus a new (jQuery) object

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to items that have been pushed, and then do a basic check:
Instead of:

```
favorites.push($(this).clone())
```

you can do:

```
if( !$(this).hasClass("pushed") ) {
    favorites.push( $(this).addClass("pushed").clone() );
}
```

Comment: You could do `$(this).not('.pushed')` too.

Comment: @JaredFarrish yes, and it's more readable too, but I tend not to use the filters, since they are [slower](http://jsperf.com/is-vs-hasclass22/2).

Comment: True enough. In massive lists of DOM `class`-name tests, you certainly have a point.

Answer (score 0):

Just push the element itself instead of cloning it:

```
favorites.push($(this))
```

The added benefit is that it gives the user a clue that the item has already be added.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9Dmcg/6/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your looking for [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). It returns the index of the value on an array. Returns -1 if not found.

It is a new array method, so you will need a polyfill for it to work on old browsers.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var favorites = [];
    var counter = 0;

    $('.containers').on('click', function(){
        var clone = $(this).clone(); // caching element

        if (favorites.indexOf(clone) !== -1) {
            favorites.push(clone);
        }

        $('.favorite').append(favorites);
    });
});
```